# Increasing or decreasing the item in Listview Android

Tags: java, android, list, listview, android-listview

I am using android studio. Code Java. I bring the data in the json file to listview. When I press the increase and decrease button, I want to bring it to the textview. I just want to increase or decrease the number of products I click. I couldn't access the buttons and textview inside the listview. How can I do it?

```
try {

            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(LoadFromJsonAssets());
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            JSONArray array =obj.getJSONArray("domestic");
            HashMap<String,String> list;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject o=array.getJSONObject(i);
                String productName=o.getString("productName");
                String productPrice=o.getString("productPrice");
                String productPic=o.getString("productPic");


                final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(productPic, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);


                list= new HashMap<>();
                list.put("productName",productName);
                list.put("productPrice",productPrice);
                list.put("productPic",Integer.toString(resourceId) );
                arrayList.add(list);
            }
            final ListAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(this,arrayList,R.layout.list_view_design,new String[]{"productName","productPrice","productPic"},new int[]{R.id.productName,R.id.productPrice,R.id.productPic});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

listview design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/productPic"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lin2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/productPic"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Product price"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/turkishlira"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="₺"></TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/decreasing "
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/negative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/counterrrr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            ></TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Increasing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/positive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I cannot comment. Does the below not work?
Find it by:

```
final TextView textViewCounter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.counterrrr);
```

and then set the text as needed:

```
// could be wrongly typed, just from the top of my head.
String currentCount = textViewCounter.getText();
int newCount = Integer.parseInt(currentCount) +/- 1;
textViewCounter.setText(String.valueOf(newCount));
```

Comment: i tried it doesn't work